# Buscar imagens dinamicamente em uma pasta

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, aplicação-web

Estou aprendendo a mexer com visualização de imagens para Web.
Estou praticando com um projeto, onde eu precisava monitorar todas as imagens que eu tenho dentro de uma pasta no projeto, e mostrar na minha página, todas essas imagens dentro dessa pasta, porém será exibido uma a uma em um intervalo de tempo. Em Javascript eu consigo fazer isso? Se sim, alguém poderia me instruir como proceder?

Obrigado!

Comment: Depende. Só é possível se seu sistema for em NodeJS, neste caso você consegue monitorar uma pasta do seu servidor usando a função [`fs.watch`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswatchfilename-options-listener) ou [`fsPromises.watch`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromiseswatchfilename-options). Para exibir isso no navegador, é necessário trabalhar com eventos (socket.io, ex) ou salvar essa informação em algum local e verificar usando Timer + Ajax

Comment: Opa, obrigado @ValdeirPsr!

Comment: O que seria "monitorar"? Se for apenas para exibir todas as imagens dentro de uma pasta na web, você pode utilizar a função scandir.

Comment: Bom dia @V.Salles, monitorar, digo mostrar realmente todas as imagens que estão dentro da pasta "images" no projeto, independente se eu remover uma imagem ou adicionar outra, terá que mostrar todas as imagens, porém 1 por vez na página.

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta.

Answer (score -3):

Supondo que você deseja exibir todas as imagens de uma pasta em um servidor da Web usando JavaScript, existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso. Uma delas é usar uma solicitação AJAX para buscar as imagens do servidor e, em seguida, exibi-las na página da web. Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso utilizando javascript puro:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exibir imagens de uma pasta utilizando Javascript Puro</title>
    <style>
        #image-gallery img {
            max-height: 200px; /* Defina a altura máxima desejada para as imagens */
            width: auto; /* Deixe a largura ser ajustada automaticamente */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image-gallery"></div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Cria um objeto XMLHttpRequest
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Abre uma conexão para a pasta "images/" no servidor
            xhr.open("GET", "images/", true);
            // Define a função a ser executada quando a solicitação Ajax for concluída
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Verifica se a solicitação foi bem-sucedida e se o estado está completo
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    // Obtém a resposta da solicitação como uma string de texto
                    var images = this.responseText;
                    // Cria um novo objeto DOMParser para analisar a string de texto como um documento HTML
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(images, "text/html");
                    // Obtém todas as tags "a" do documento HTML
                    var links = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
                    // Itera por cada tag "a"
                    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                        // Obtém o nome do arquivo do link
                        var file = links[i].getAttribute("href");
                        // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
                        if (file.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                            // Cria uma nova imagem
                            var img = document.createElement("img");
                            // Define o atributo "src" da imagem com o caminho completo para o arquivo de imagem na pasta "images/"
                            img.src = "images/" + file;
                            // Adiciona a nova imagem à div "image-gallery"
                            document.getElementById("image-gallery").appendChild(img);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            // Envia a solicitação Ajax
            xhr.send();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

O código acima já é capaz de exibir todas as imagens presentes no interior do diretório (Apenas lembrando, esse diretório também precisa estar no servidor).

**Explicação**

No código acima, nós adicionamos um evento de escuta denominado DOMContentLoaded, que garante que o código JavaScript só será executado após o carregamento completo da página. Em seguida, criamos uma nova instância do objeto XMLHttpRequest e abrimos uma conexão para a pasta "images/" no servidor.

Quando a solicitação Ajax é bem-sucedida, armazenamos a resposta como uma string de texto e a analisamos usando um objeto DOMParser para criar um documento HTML. Em seguida, pegamos todas as tags "a" do documento e iteramos por elas, verificando se cada link contém um arquivo de imagem. Se sim, criamos uma nova imagem usando o método document.createElement e definimos seu atributo "src" com o caminho completo para as imagens na pasta "images". Finalmente, adicionamos a nova imagem à div "image-gallery" usando o método appendChild. Esse é um exemplo não dependente do jQuery, utiliza apenas JavaScript puro para fazer a solicitação Ajax e manipular o documento HTML.

Entretanto, em sua pergunta original, você também solicitou uma forma de exibir as imagens uma a uma. Nesse caso, substitua o código anterior por este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exibir imagens de uma pasta utilizando Javascript Puro</title>
    <style>
        #image-gallery img {
            max-height: 200px; /* Defina a altura máxima desejada para as imagens */
            width: auto; /* Deixe a largura ser ajustada automaticamente */
            display: none; /* Oculta todas as imagens inicialmente */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="image-gallery"></div>
    <script>
        var index = 0; // Índice da imagem atual
        var images = []; // Array para armazenar as imagens

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Cria um objeto XMLHttpRequest
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Abre uma conexão para a pasta "images/" no servidor
            xhr.open("GET", "images/", true);
            // Define a função a ser executada quando a solicitação Ajax for concluída
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Verifica se a solicitação foi bem-sucedida e se o estado está completo
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                    // Obtém a resposta da solicitação como uma string de texto
                    var imagesHtml = this.responseText;
                    // Cria um novo objeto DOMParser para analisar a string de texto como um documento HTML
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(imagesHtml, "text/html");
                    // Obtém todas as tags "a" do documento HTML
                    var links = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
                    // Itera por cada tag "a"
                    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                        // Obtém o nome do arquivo do link
                        var file = links[i].getAttribute("href");
                        // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
                        if (file.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                            // Cria uma nova imagem
                            var img = document.createElement("img");
                            // Define o atributo "src" da imagem com o caminho completo para o arquivo de imagem na pasta "images/"
                            img.src = "images/" + file;
                            // Adiciona a nova imagem ao array "images"
                            images.push(img);
                            // Adiciona a nova imagem à div "image-gallery"
                            document.getElementById("image-gallery").appendChild(img);
                        }
                    }

                    // Exibe a primeira imagem
                    images[0].style.display = "block";

                    // Define um intervalo de tempo para exibir as imagens
                    setInterval(function() {
                        // Oculta a imagem atual
                        images[index].style.display = "none";
                        // Incrementa o índice da imagem atual
                        index = (index + 1) % images.length;
                        // Exibe a próxima imagem
                        images[index].style.display = "block";
                    }, 2000
                ); // Muda de imagem a cada 2 segundos (2000 milissegundos)
            }
            };
            // Envia a solicitação Ajax
            xhr.send();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Se a resposta o ajudou, por favor, considere aceita-la como válida.

Comment: Eu consegui fazer com PHP, deu certo de trazer as imagens para a página. Obrigado pela ajuda @V.Salles.